# Customising WP user activation email

Tags: email, email-verification

I'm trying to customise the default 'new user activation' email, but none of the hooks/filters semm to apply to that specific email. To be clear it's the one that looks like:

```
To activate your user, please click the following link:

https://website.com/?page=account_activation&key=12345612384
```

All I can find in the docs is password reset and new user notification emails.

The closest I could find was the `wpmu_signup_user_notification_email` filter, but that only applies to multisite installations. There doesn't appear to be an equivalent for single-site installations.

This is what I tried (using the WPMU version):

```
function custom_activation_email( $message, $user, $user_email, $key, $meta ) {

    $email_body = email_elements('header');

    $email_body .= '<p style="margin-top:0;">Hi there </p>';
    $email_body .= '<p>You&#39;re almost there! Click the button below to activate your account.</p>';
    $email_body .= '<p><a href="https://website.com?page=account_activation&key='.$key.'" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 16px; font-family: Inter, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 8px; line-height: 20px; display: block; font-weight: 500 !important; white-space: nowrap; background-color: #007456; padding: 12px 24px; border: 1px solid #007456;width:fit-content;text-align: center;margin:20px 0;">See all jobs</a></p>';
    $email_body .= '<p style="margin-bottom:20px">If that doesn&#39;t work, copy and paste this into your browser: https://website.com/?page=account_activation&key='.$key.'</p>';
    $email_body .= 'If you have any problems, please reply to this email.';

    $email_body .= email_elements('footer');

    $subject = 'Activate your account';

    return array( 'to' => $user_email, 'subject' => $subject, 'message' => $email_body, 'headers' => '' );

}
add_filter('wpmu_signup_user_notification_email', 'custom_activation_email', 10, 5);
```

(`email_elements` is just resuable opening and closing html and body tags with styling)

Comment: Are you sure that's core WordPress sending that email? I don't recognise it. AFAICR the process is 1) user fills in the register form; 2) site emails them a generated password. There's no activation step, except for creating mulitsites as you've found.